# multiple rows from one table

Tags: php, sql, arrays, row, fetch

Im trying to echo out two things from database, why wont this work? and how do i get this to work. Im just learning php so if this is a realy dumb question im sorry.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, team FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$team = $row['team'];

echo = $user_id;
echo = $team;`
```

I'm thankful for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tpaksu already mentioned, you need brackets around the statements you want your loop to execute.

Second, the correct format for echo is

```
echo $user_id;
```

And two other, rather fundamental remarks

- the mysql calls are **deprecated** which means that they have been replaced by newer alternatives (specifically either mysqli or better still PDO).  Don't waste time learning howto use the mysql* family of calls, switch to mysqli or preferably PDO **now**.
- an sql statement like `"SELECT user_id, team FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");` where a variable is included as-is in an SQL statement is a huge risk for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You could waste precious time devising all kinds of clever schemes to sanitize variables before inclusion, or you could learn to do it the only right way, that is, by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  It may be less intuitive at first sight but you'll quickly get used toit.

This will transform your code into something like this:

```
<?php
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_id, team FROM users WHERE username = ?");
  if ($stmt->execute(array($username))) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $user_id = $row['user_id'];
      $team = $row['team'];

      echo $user_id;
      echo $team;
    }
  }
?>
```

which is injection proof and uses up to date technology.  As a bonus side effect, it will be a lot easier to adapt to other brands of databases.

Comment: Thanks! that's very helpful! I'll look more into that pdo stuff.
I hope i don't have to change to much in my code tough :)

Answer (score 3):

you should use brackets to group code like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, team FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $team = $row['team'];

    echo $user_id;
    echo $team;
}
```

Comment: ooh.. thank you very much, i wasnt so far off then :)
Guess i have to read about those brackets, i often have problem with those. Where can i read about them?

Comment: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp) is a good resource to begin with.

Comment: and accept this answer if you think it is the correct solution to your problem.

Comment: @tpaksu don't just send people to w3schools, [see the discussion on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource) as that site still insists on teaching people the mysql_ family of calls that's **deprecated**, among other sins.

Comment: Ok, I will take this into account on my later posts. Thank you.